# How fast can we approximate a real number using $n$ comparisons to it?

Tags: algorithms, real-numbers, computational-complexity

Here is a mathematical game:

> Let $x > 0$ be a real number. We know nothing about $x$, but we are given a black box that inputs any real number $y$ and tells us if $y$ is greater, less than or equal to $x$.
>
> We are tasked to find the best possible approximation for $x$, but we are allowed to call the black box no more than $n$ times.

To illustrate, here’s one possible (rather naive) solution:

> We define a sequence of rational numbers  $(p_i/q_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ as follows. First set $(p_1,q_1)=(1,1)$. For $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, we input $p_i/q_i$ into the black box, and subsequently define:
>
> $$(p_{i+1},q_{i+1}) = \begin{cases} (p_i+1,q_i) &\mbox{if } p_n/q_n <x \\ 
> (p_i,q_i+1) & \mbox{if } p_n/q_n > x \\ (p_i,q_i) & \mbox{if } p_n/q_n =x \end{cases}$$

The above sequence of fractions surely converges to $x$ as $n\to \infty$, and what's more the error term $\varepsilon_n :=|x - p_n/q_n|$ decays in $O(1/n).$

Is there an algorithm such that the error term decays quadratically? Cubically? Exponentially?

Comment: It's worth noting that the rate of decay of the error term always depends on $x$, no matter what we do. If $x$ is chosen from, say, a Cauchy distribution, then the *expected* error will always remain infinite for any $n$, since there's a positive probability that the black box says "greater" for the first $n$ steps, in which case there's no good guess to make.

Comment: @MishaLavrov If we use the usual unbounded Euclidean error, yes. If we use a bounded norm on $\mathbb{R}$, we can talk sensibly about the asymptotic $n$-dependence.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Alice has an algorithm that could address the seemingly easier problem of just managing this for $x\in(0,\,1)$. Bob's favourite strictly increasing function $f$ from $(0,\,1)$ to $\Bbb R^+$ (it might for example be $t\mapsto t/(1-t)$) allows him to estimate $x$ by using Alice's technique to estimate $f^{-1}(x)$. If Alice's method would try $y$ as such an estimate, Bob just uses $f(y)$ as an estimate of $x$ instead. Thus we can focus instead on how Alice solves her bounded problem.

Here's something Alice could try: start with $0.5$ so we halve the range of values of $x$, go to the middle of that and so on. For example, if $x=0.83624$ the estimates are $0.5,\,0.75,\,0.875,\,0.8125,\,0.94375,\,\cdots$. This is called a binary search. Our error in $x$ is $O(2^{-n})$. Going back to Bob's harder problem (i.e. the one you asked about), the error in estimating $x\in\Bbb R^+$ is by the chain rule approximately $f'f^{-1}(x)$ times the error in estimating $f^{-1}(x)$. Again, the error is $O(2^{-n})$. If you pick $f$ not to flatten too fast, the $f'f^{-1}(x)$ factor won't be too bad. Fo example the rational function I suggested above would be a much better choice of $f$ than $t\mapsto \operatorname{artanh} t$.

Can we do better than a binary search? Not really. Each yes/no question of the black box gives us $1$ bit of information, so can only halve the measure of values of $x$ consistent with our information. The advantage of Alice's bounded problem is it lets us work with finite-measure sets.